# Google sheet - extract date+time from a cell contains Chinese characters

Tags: datetime, extract

I am craving for a formula to extract date + time from a cell which contains Chinese characters. I am having a hard time to get the formula to slove my problem.  Grateful for your help !!!!!

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 2024年2月27日 上午05:49:58 | 227054958 |
| 2024年2月26日 下午08:42:18 | 226084218 |
| 2024年3月1日 下午10:21:17 | 31102117 |

Thx in advance !!!

I keep having error when I was trying to use the REGEXEXTRACT and REGEXREPLACE Function